# MySQL inserts zeroes (0) in CHAR field

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a database table that features a field that lists flag width-to-height ratios, like these: 2:3, 7:10. I designated the field CHAR, but it displays 2:03, inserting a zero.

My query language is PHP (PDO).

Does anyone know how I fix that? I changed the field to INT, but that doesn't work. Thx.

On Edit: I posted my query below. It's pretty big, but I highlighted the field Ration in bold.

```
SELECT F.ID, F.IDArea, F.Uses, **F.Ratio**, F.Design, F.Design2,
 F.R, F.W, F.B, F.G, F.Y, F.N, GS.DesigGen, GS.Date, C.IDArea, C.Color, C.Order,
 GG.N Number, GG.IDArea, GG.URL GURL, GG.Name GName, GG.Type, GG.IDParent, GG.IDParent2,    GG.Parent, GG.ParentName, GG.Parent2, GG.IDReg
FROM gs_flags AS F
LEFT JOIN gs AS GS ON GS.IDArea = F.IDArea
LEFT JOIN gs_flags_color AS C ON C.IDArea = F.IDArea
LEFT JOIN gw_geog AS GG ON GG.IDArea = F.IDArea
WHERE GG.Type = 'nat' AND F.Design != '0' OR GG.Type = 'dep'  AND F.Design != '0' AND   GS.DesigGen = 'flag'
GROUP BY F.IDArea ORDER BY GG.Name
```

Comment: what is your query to insert and read?

Comment: Would it make any difference if it was VARCHAR with 4-5 data length?

Comment: @ ncdreamy - It was originally VARCHAR, but that didn't work any better than CHAR. I think I set the length at something like 8 or 9, because some values are longer - 110:120, or something like that.

Comment: Are you sure that unnecessary formatting happens when `SELECT`ing? In other words, what do you see when viewing the table outside of your code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by viewing the table outside of its code. This is how I define the value: $Ratio = $row['Ratio']; I then display it like this:

echo <<<EOD
   <tr>
     <td>$Ratio</td>

Comment: OK, now I understand what you meant...I looked at the table in phpMyAdmin, and the code is messed up right there. I could have sworn I checked that, and it was OK. But right now the table includes a value 1:02 where it should be 1:2. So it looks like my problem is more related to importing my CSV files into phpMyAdmin.